# How to get another language working on Registration and Auth pages?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am trying to change the language in Laravel, for now the Auth / registration and login pages. For some reason the language doesnt change.

I have the laravel language pack, set up /resources/lang/nl with auth.php, registration.php, nl.json, pagination.php and password.php. Some messages get translated (For example, when you enter the wrong password), but validation remains in english, and the form itself as well.

```
$locale = App::getLocale(); shows 'nl'
```

I would like to find a way to change the language on the actual pages, and the verification messages to Dutch as well.

Comment: Did you place the json in `lang/nl.json` or in `lang/nl/nl.json`?

Comment: No, i didnt, now it works, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The error was in the position of the json file.

This should be placed in resources/lang, and not in resources/lang/nl